# Is the firmware of the Canon 430EX III-RT updatable?

Tags: flash, firmware

I notice in the menus of the Canon 430EX III-RT the firmware version is shown (mine shows "Ver 1.0.1").  Is this just for diagnostic purposes?  Or, is it possible to update the firmware?  I can't see any obvious way for a user to update the firmware as there's no USB port.  So, if it can be done, I'm assuming Canon would need to do it.  Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when there is an issue between a Canon EOS camera and a Canon flash, if possible Canon will issue an update for the *camera* to work around the issue. I'm not sure I've ever seen a user accessible firmware update for a Canon flash.

There have been recalls/updates that require sending a flash in to Canon to fix a bug.

[This advisory](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/product-advisories/detail/!ut/p/z1/rZHLboMwEEW_pkvLIwwGljxakb6iPJQEb5BjTOs2GAJuSPv1daqsWpGqUr0a22dm7szFDG8w0_ygnrhRjeY7e88ZLR5mWZBNErifLu9iiK7j6YLQlEBC8AozzIQ2rXnGueC60YWWwyC3Rds15Zsw_RWcI8TLg-qbTkn7VqmuHngnUd9KWe6UkRRAHlFnTgVboUqcu9SjDuUEEbn1kUvcEIWV4yERBOB4whWce3j9m0Jmv2HkRGDz2RcyVsGF7wDMQx8imtIsfIxhMvN-AKvYtUCYJsS5ObU5AxdU5HYKf1SDQ_Dij2u5vTiUXYt1Vr3s9yyy9jXayKPBm__xr63rgLyj13n2sazqdfQJJPzqEg!!/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) regarding the firmware for certain serial number ranges of the 600EX-RT and ST-E3-RT requires shipping the unit(s) to a Canon Service Center for inspection and service. When that advisory was issued over three years ago, [Brian Worley questioned why Canon does not make flashes updatable by the end user](https://www.p4pictures.com/2015/12/canon-speedlite-600ex-rt-st-e3-rt-firmware-update/).